# Intersection of unbounded decreasing open sets is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X$ is a Polish space. For any real number $c$, let $(c_n)$ be a convergent sequence that converges to $c$ such that $c < c_n$ for all $n$. 
For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, denote $A_n = (-\infty,c_n)$. Is it true that $f^{-1}(-\infty,c] = \cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f^{-1}(-\infty,c_n)$ is closed, where $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the property that for any real number $d$, its pre-image $f^{-1}(-\infty,d)$ is open in $X$?

Comment: $\varnothing$ is open.

Comment: Second: For an increasing sequence $(c_n)$ converging to $c$ it does not hold $$f^{-1}(-\infty,c] = \cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f^{-1}(-\infty,c_n)$$ so your you start with a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Gono: I am assuming the sequence is decreasing to $c$.

Comment: Ah, I haven't seen that, sry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample for both open and closed is

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( (-\tfrac{1}{n}, \tfrac{1}{n}) \cup (2,3) \right) = \{ 0 \} \cup (2,3) $$

Comment: What is your $A_n$?

Comment: @Idonknow: I don't have any $A_n$: I'm responding to your question "Is the intersection of decreasing open sets closed?"

Comment: But my question restrict open sets to be unbounded.

Comment: Then use $(2,\infty)$ rather than $(2,3)$.